# Linux bash script asks for user input runs at time interval

Tags: linux

I would like to write a bash script which upon asking for user conformation compresses a folder. The bash script will be executed once a day ask user for conformation, if conformation is given the command will be executed.

Comment: This does not make any sense at all, sorry. You want to think about this again. Several issues here: 1. what if no user is currently there to confirm? 2. _what_ user should confirm? (Linux is a _multi user environment_) 3. why a confirmation, if it is started on a time based schedule?

Comment: There are no issues, I have a script that needs to ask the currently active user at a time interval for conformation before running a command.

Comment: This would be useful in several scenarios which you should be familiar with such as system updates, backups and virus scans. Simply running these automatically may not be useful as the command may be interrupted by a system shutdown or the user may not want the processor to be busy.

Comment: 1. Not relevant, I guess in that case I would program the command to run anyway.
2. Updated the question to reflect the fact that there is only one user.
3. Because sometimes I may not see it fit for the command to run, for example if I am going to be using the processor for other tasks.

Comment: Just to clarify I use linux for my personal desktop, I know most people view linux as something used to run servers or to host multiple users.

Comment: I see a point in asking "the" currently active user if a certain task should now be started or not. Typically the approaches here are different, for example using higher nice levels so that things like backups do _not_ interfere with the interactive usage of the system, also your approach raises other questions, like what happens if the user denies such a question, but I admit that you have this requirement and want to find a solution. You could elegantly use your x sessions dbus for a nitification, but not for a question. For this you will have to implement a simple server, I am afraid...

Comment: Another option would be to open a window on the active X server display. You can control which display is addressed for graphical output by setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable. There are two issues you have to solve for that: first you obviously have to find out _which_ X server display to connect to if multiple are running and you have to grant access from within the running session. That second can be done via the profile scripts, take a look at the `xhost` command for that. But keep in mind that this is limited to an X server based desktop, it probably wont work under Wayland...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron runs a process without a connected terminal, so getting user response is going to be a problem.  You need to set up some kind of human intervention with email, for example.

If you have to have input consider doing this another way:
send mail to the night operator, let's call him/her "noc", well before the cron job runs - you can do this as a crontab call to a small shell script as well:

```
echo 'run  /path/to/setup.shl' | mailx -s 'action required' noc@mycompany.com
```

setup.shl bash example make 'N' the default:

```
echo 'N' > /path/to/controlfile

read -p "Run cronjob foo? " -n 1 -r

if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
   echo 'Y' > /path/to/controlfile
fi
```

Next, modify the foo cronjob on the very first line to read the control file, and run if 'Y' exit if 'N'